# How to load data into android from the web

Tags: android, eclipse, parsing, sqlite

I have recently started Android Development, and I am building random projects so that I can learn more.
One project i am doing is where user enters the name of a movie, and the app loads some data about the movie (e.g. rating, directed by, cast etc.) from the web. I was thinking of using IMDb to get the movie details.
But I am confused as how to get the specific data from a webpage and load it in the application. I have looked into SQLiteDatabases, JSON Parsing as well as SAX Parsing, but still am not clear as how to get the data from the IMDb website. 
Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You need a Http-Client.

Here a Quick and Dirty implementation:
http://www.remwebdevelopment.com/dev/a20/Android-A-Quick-and-Dirty-Http-Client.html

You need the classes HttpRequest and HttpResponse
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpRequest.html

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. Although I need to do a little advanced than this. This activity will get all of the data from the page xml and populate the textview.
I need some idea about how to get specific data from the webpage. Suppose I open the url for a movie on imdb and i want to populate the textview only with the rating of the movie. Can you help me with this..??

Comment: then you need to write a little webcrawler.
the page is always the same way? so you can use sax parsing as you have written it. something like that: [Sax parsing on android](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example)

Comment: Thankyou, this somewhat helped.
Yes the page is more or less the same. It is a simple project to think, load a imdb page for the movie user entered and import some of its details.
Thanks a lot for this though. I will let you know if this worked or not.